# How to detect button press in a timed loop

Tags: java, loops, button, timer

I am a beginner in Java and am trying to practice my skills.  I am trying to create a game that requires the player to hit a button repeatedly for a certain amount of time.  I want to do something like this to generate a number of how many times a specific key, like the space bar, has been pressed in a specific time, for instance, 30 seconds

```
while(time!=0){
//amount of time
    if (isPressing("w")){
    buttonPressed ++;

    }
//decrements amount of time  
}
```

Ultimately once the time runs out I want to exit the loop and return the number of times the button has been pressed.  I am unsure of how to actually accomplish this as the timers I have found are looped to repeat an action on an interval.  Can anyone help give me some direction?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the time in milliseconds with:

Following your example of 30 seconds,you would do something like this:

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
while(System.currentTimeMillis() - time < 30000){//30000 is 30 seconds in milliseconds
    if (isPressing("w")){
        buttonPressed ++;
    }
}
```

It would work by comparing the start time with the time after every iteration.